# PHP- Cannot reference method from mysqli class in another class

Tags: methods, mysqli, extends, mysql-real-escape-string, inheritance

I am trying to inherit all methods and properties from superglobal mysqli class into my db class.

Here is the DB class:

```
class DB extends mysqli
{
    protected $mysqli;

    public function __construct () {
        // connect to MySQL
        $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

        // output error if unable to connect
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .     $mysqli->connect_error;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main Meetings class:

```
class Meetings
{

    function __construct () {
        require_once('../include/classes/db.class.php');
        $db = new DB();

        $field = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['about']);

    }

}
```

In the Meetings class, I want to be able to call the real_escape_string method through the instantiated DB class that was inherited by the superglobal mysqli class.

I am getting this error: Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() [mysqli.real-escape-string]: Couldn't fetch DB

Answer (score 0):

Oops!
You created the DB object, and the db object creates an another instance of the mysqli class. You should not call new mysqli, but you should call

```
parent::__construct('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname')
```

or

```
    parent::mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname')
```

I don't know which is the good format for the mysqli constructor.

After this, you don't need the mysql property in the DB class, because in this situation, your mysqli property is equal with the $this of the DB class. So, not $mysqli->connect_errno, but $this->connect_errno is right.

Comment: Duh, what am I thinking? Thanks!